# How to do I update my python environment, my python setup is a mess and I installed it in many different ways

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

When I first installed Python, I think I did it using the website. But soon after, I found that there were many ways to install python, I started hearing things like pyenv, pip (am familiar with this), anaconda, etc., and I used Homebrew the second time.

There were lots of terminal work to do that I really didn't understand. Now I downloaded python again into my computer and when I use python on the terminal, it does not reflect the updated version.
[image]

but I downloaded the latest Python 3.10 version. I don't know how to fix this.

P.S. I would be open to completely removing Python from my system, and even Homebrew and start from scratch, as I only really got Homebrew for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, relevant [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1987/).

I'm sure you'll get many different answers, but after struggling for months with environment management when I first started coding, I finally ended up finding that pyenv was the best option for me.

You can use Homebrew to install **pyenv** and **virtualenv**.

Pyenv installation instructions for MacOS: [https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#homebrew-in-macos](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)
Virtualenv installation instructions for MacOS: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

Of course you'll have to make sure to carefully follow the installation instructions for whatever terminal shell you use, `zsh`, `bash`, etc. The linked GitHub installation instructions explain this.

After you've successfully installed the two, you can use pyenv to install specific base versions of Python, e.g., `pyenv install 3.8.8`.

You can then use virtualenv to create specific closed environments for each Python version. I use this frequently for building/testing with packages that aren't compatible with one another.

You can activate the environments with commands as so: `pyenv virtualenv 3.8.8 app_build`, and to create another one, `pyenv virtualenv 3.8.8 app_testing`.

Then you can *activate* each environment for usage in your terminal or IDE by using `pyenv activate app_build`, etc. After activation, you can install packages, and they will only be installed in the activated environment.

Pyenv integrates very nicely with Visual Studio Code as well. I can speak more to that if you're interested.

I used anaconda for a while, but it wasn't well suited for app development/PyQt5, so I abandoned it. I personally like much pyenv much more, as I feel more in control with it.

Answer (score 0):

"python3" is the python of the system. Same as "/usr/bin/python3":

```
/usr/bin/python3
Python 3.8.9 (default, Oct 26 2021, 07:25:54) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

You want to use "/usr/local/bin/python3":

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 21 2021, 03:23:44) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose the python version you would like to install from:

   pyenv install --list

I have chosen 3.10.1.

2. Install python:

   pyenv install 3.10.1
3. Switch to it in the current shell:

   pyenv shell 3.10.1
4. Create virtual environment for the project:

   python -m venv <new_env_directory>
5. Activate the newly created environment:

   <new_env_directory>/bin/activate